# Cant click on a specific button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I cant add an item to the cart because the button is not being selected.

[the button in question is the "ADD TO CART" and its only classification is its class called "btn_primary btn_inventory".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b58gJ.png)

[this button should add the item selected to the cart as shown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7leTa.png)

here is the non working code i used to get it to select a random button and to click on it:

```
WebElement areaInventory = navegador.findElement(By.id("inventory_container"));
        List<WebElement> l1 = areaInventory.findElements(By.className("btn_primary btn_inventory"));
        for(int i=0;i< l1.size();i++){
            Random r = new Random();
            l1.get(r.nextInt(6)).click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the below mentioned change.

Change `List<WebElement> l1 = areaInventory.findElements(By.className("btn_primary btn_inventory"));`

to `List<WebElement> l1 = areaInventory.findElements(By.cssSelector(".btn_primary.btn_inventory"));`